# Way to build UI of Firefox OS

Tags: user-interface, firefox-os

Recently Firefox OS has been arrived in market and developers like me and my friends are very curious for developing apps for this mobile . I have started developing apps for this mobile os by seeing tutorial from internet .

For android , there is well facilitated opportunities to bulid GUI of application by dragging and drops . Does same facility exist for firefox OS ?

To be more specific , suppose I want to include a date-picker for Firefox mobile OS like the following screen :

[image]

The code for above date-picker UI is as following :

```
<datepicker type="grid" value="2007-03-26"/>
```

Is there any way such that I drag and drops the UI and the code for UI will be automatically built like Android ? It will be very helpful for me if there exists such arrangements . I have searched a lot of tutorial in internet but can not get satisfactory answer .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no drag and drop UI for building apps specifically for Firefox OS, but apps on Firefox OS are web apps so that means you can use any existing web development tool to build your apps.

There are a set of building blocks for standard pieces of UI at http://buildingfirefoxos.com but these are really for built-in apps and were not implemented with the intention of re-use for third party web apps. You might instead want to use one of many web UI frameworks available like JQuery UI.

In the particular case of the datepicker you mention, the web already has an HTML tag for that. If you use a [input type="date"] element in your app (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input), it will use the system date picker which is optimised for mobile use.

You can develop your web app inside a web browser, but if you'd like to see what your app will look like running in Firefox OS you can use the Firefox OS Simulator addon for Firefox https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firefox-os-simulator/ This will show you the built-in datepicker interface.

Good luck with developing your app!